# Changing bevel angle

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I am working on a model, and now I have stumbled upon a problem. I want to change the angle of my bevel, but all this while its still non-destructive. Is there a way to do this, without the need of applying the bevel modifier?

The thing is easily representable with the default cube, that's why I am showing with it.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to bevel by percentage of edge length.

1. Set *Width Type > Percent*
2. Uncheck *Clamp Overlap*
3. Add loops and slide them to control the angle

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Aside from @Jachym's method, you can also do something like it with a custom 2-segment profile, with the central control-point set to Vector, and clipped against one edge of the graph...

[image]

... but as you can see from the tilted cube in the illustration, it still means introducing a (bad topology) extra edge.

It would be very nice if Blender had asymmetrical bevels: if you could, as it were, move the end-points of the custom profile, instead of introducing a new point in the middle.

Comment: Nice! This is the method I wanted to show, but couldn't make it work :).

Comment: @JachymMichal  yes ... but actually I've 'always' used your way.. better topo for subdiv. Actually haven't done that, either,  much, I usually just model destructively.